# Assigning Cell Value based on a range of values (Using =ifs)

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to use the value of a numerical cell to define a text cell with logic.

If cell F2  >= 17 AND <= 18 THEN define as "Preservation Class".
I basically need to repeat this 3 more times for 3 more ranges.

Below is what I came up with, which does not work. Can someone take a look and see what I'm doing incorrectly? It says that I have entered too few arguments.

```
=ifs(F2>=17,f2<=18,"Preservation Class",F2>=14,f2<=16,"Retention Class",F2>=11,f2<=13,"Partial Retention Class",F2>=9,f2<=10,"Modification Class",F2>=0,f2<=8,"Rehabilitation Class")
```

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBvOx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=INDEX({"Rehabilitation Class","Modification Class","Partial Retention Class","Retention Class","Preservation Class"},MATCH(F2,{0,9,11,14,17}))
```

If you want IFS(), it resolves left to right so the second criteria is not needed:

```
=ifs(F2>=17,"Preservation Class",F2>=14,"Retention Class",F2>=11,"Partial Retention Class",F2>=9,"Modification Class",F2>=0,"Rehabilitation Class")
```

Comment: wow thank you so much. Two follow up questions. What is the advantage of using index instead of IFS?

Second question, how could I reference cell F@ if it is in another sheet?

Comment: I find it easier to maintain the INDEX() other wise not sure which is faster.